# Angular 2 Directive Getting reference to Component inner HTML children

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

```
import { ContentChild, Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[mydirective]' })
export class MyDirective {

    constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {}

    @Input() myData: string;
    @ContentChild('first') firstDiv: HTMLDivElement;

    ngAfterContentInit(){
      console.log(this.firstDiv); //hope this would grab the element inside the component html file. 
      this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'myclass', ( this.myData !==undefined ) );
    }
}
```

I currently have an angular2 component built, and I'm trying to add a new directive that adds a class to the first node of the components inner HTML. The following is the structure of my HTML in the DOM after the component renders:

```
<mycomponent [mydirective]="mydirectiveData" >
 <div (where I want my class)>
 </div>
</mycomponent>
```

My html in the component looks like this: `<div class="myComponent" #first>`

With the above code, my directive wrongly adds the class to a level above my template in addition, it tightly couples the class to the code. My question is how do I reference the first element inside my component from the directive? I'm using the latest version of angular.

```
<mycomponent [mydirective]="mydirectiveData" class="(where my class shows up)" >
 <div>
 </div>
</mycomponent>
```

Comment: try adding anchor to the `<div #first` and using `@ContentChild('first') `inside the directive

Comment: @Maximus <div class="myComponent" #first>.... inside Directive: I tried grabbing  @ContentChild('first') firstDiv: HTMLDivElement; its null when console.log( this.firstDiv )

Comment: where do you log it? it has to be done inside `ngAfterContentInit` hook

Comment: @Maximus yep - logged it in the Directive updated question to reflect change.

Comment: yeah, that's tricky... needs investigation